# Data type conversion in SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following query in which I am trying to add two columns which are of data type `nvarchar`. It is giving me only concatenation. Please have a look on query that is written below:

```
SELECT 
    T0.[ItmsGrpCod],
    T1.[Dscription],
    T3.[OnHand] as 'Opening balance',
    (T1.[U_TotalGraded]) + (T1.[U_TotalRej]),
    T1.[U_TotalGraded], T1.[U_TotalRej], 
    T2.[DocDate] 
FROM 
    OITM T0
INNER JOIN 
    IGN1 T1 ON T0.[ItemCode] = T1.[ItemCode] 
INNER JOIN 
    OIGN T2 ON T1.[DocEntry] = T2.[DocEntry] 
INNER JOIN 
    OITW T3 ON T0.[ItemCode] = T3.[ItemCode]
```

Now if `T1.[U_TotalGraded] = 12` and `T1.[U_TotalRej] = 3` then I am getting `(T1.[U_TotalGraded])+(T1.[U_TotalRej]) = 123`  instead of adding.

Comment: I suggest to search about `CAST` or `CONVERT`

Comment: add in query. i tried. but getting some another error. please add in query and update . @Lamak

Comment: Try to cast the columns you want to add

Comment: Don't store numeric values in varchar columns... Whenever you have to do `CAST`, take a look at the table design and ask yourself if the data type need to be changed.

Comment: Applying a `+` to two `nvarchar` columns **will** concatenate - that's what the `+` operator does for `nvarchar` columns. If you want to have a numerical addition - **why on earth** are you storing your *numerical* values as `nvarchar` ?? This dosen't make sense - if those **are** numbers, then **store** them as numbers! (`int` or `decimal` or something). For those, `+` will add the values numerically

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert it to `INT` using `CAST` in following:

```
   SELECT 
       T0.[ItmsGrpCod], 
       T1.[Dscription], 
       T3.[OnHand] as 'Opening balance',
       case when isnumeric(T1.[U_TotalGraded]) = 1 and 
                 isnumeric(T1.[U_TotalRej]) = 1 
            then cast(T1.[U_TotalGraded] as int) + cast(T1.[U_TotalRej] as int) 
            else 0 -- do something if can't be converted
       end,
       T1.[U_TotalGraded], 
       T1.[U_TotalRej], 
       T2.[DocDate] 
   FROM OITM T0  
   INNER JOIN IGN1 T1 ON T0.[ItemCode] = T1.[ItemCode] 
   INNER JOIN OIGN T2 ON T1.[DocEntry] = T2.[DocEntry] 
   INNER JOIN OITW T3 ON T0.[ItemCode] = T3.[ItemCode]
```

Also you can use `ISNUMERIC` to check If It can be converted to datatype `INT`.

Comment: This will only work if those columns are guaranteed to have values that can be converted to integers, which may not be the case. If it is the case it raises the question of why the columns aren't INT type already.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist added `ISNUMERIC` to check If It can be converted to `INT`.

Comment: `ISNUMERIC` doesn't check if it can be converted to an int, it checks whether it can be converted to any numeric datatype. Use `TRY_CONVERT` instead.